# lock an operator chain while an observable item is passing through it

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I have an Observable source and an operator chain that transforms the source into a target type. Generally for each source item, up to one target is produced.

```
Source -> Operator chain -> Target
```

Operator logic is kind of complex and involves more than one async database calls using IO scheduler. I omit the details here as it does not seem to be relevant.
What I see is that new Observables are coming from the Source while a previous observable is still being processed by the chain. So it resembles some sort of pipeline. This is probably a good thing in many cases but not in mine.

So I am looking a way on how to delay the source items to coming into the chain (effectively locking it) until a previous item reaches the Target. Is there any known pattern of doing this?

One ugly solution I see is to use something like this at the beginning of the chain:

```
zip(source, signal, (source, signal)->source)
```

where signal is a custom observable for pushing a notification into every time the chain is ready to accept a new source item (one notification initially and when an item being processed reaches the end of the  chain)
But I find it a bit hacky. Can it be achieved more gracefully or using set of standard operators?

Here is the synthetic example to reproduce the behavior I do not want. 
Source is 100ms interval timer.
Operator chain is a slow (10x slower than source) async call that computes a square on Schedulers.io()
Target item is effectively a source squared.

```
Subscription s = Observable.timer(100, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .doOnNext(source->System.out.println("source: " + source))
    .concatMap(source->Observable.create(subscr->{
      Schedulers.io().createWorker().schedule(()->{
        subscr.onNext(source * source);
        subscr.onCompleted();
      }, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }))
    .doOnNext(target->System.out.println("target: " + target))
    .subscribe();
Thread.sleep(10000);
s.unsubscribe();
```

Both source and target are printed out:

```
source: 0
source: 1
source: 2
source: 3
source: 4
source: 5
source: 6
source: 7
source: 8
source: 9
source: 10
source: 11
target: 0
source: 12
source: 13
source: 14
source: 15
source: 16
source: 17
source: 18
source: 19
source: 20
target: 1
source: 21
source: 22
source: 23
source: 24
source: 25
source: 26
source: 27
source: 28
source: 29
source: 30
source: 31
target: 4
source: 32
source: 33
```

But what I would like to achieve is:

```
source: 0
target: 0
source: 1
target: 1
source: 2
target: 4
...
```

Comment: Could you write up a small example so the type of the sequence and operators become clear? Generally, you can either use `concatMap` to make sure `Observable`s are subscribed to one at a time of `flatMap` with maxConcurrent = 1.

Comment: Is your source hot like a Subject or is it like a timer that ignores backpressure like in your example?

Comment: Source is generally hot while shared with at least one subscriber (ends with .replay(1).refCount())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your source type, this can be achieved with `flatMap` parametrized to have `maxConcurrency = 1`:

```
Observable.interval(100, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.onBackpressureBuffer()
.doOnNext(source -> System.out.println("source: " + source))
.flatMap(source -> 
     Observable.just(source)
     .map(v -> v * v)
     .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), 1)
.doOnNext(target->System.out.println("target: " + target))
.subscribe();
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

This solution involves buffering but if the source is hot, you might want to choose a different backpressure strategy.

Not strictly related to the requirements but I'd like to point out that this pattern of yours:

```
Schedulers.io().createWorker().schedule(()->{
    subscr.onNext(source * source);
    subscr.onCompleted();
  }, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

leaks the worker and will fill up your system with non-reusable threads. If you really want to delay events via a ˙Worker`, you should capture and unsubscribe the worker instance:

```
Scheduler.Worker w = Schedulers.io().createWorker();
subscr.add(w);
w.schedule(() -> {
    try {
        subscr.onNext(source * source);
        subscr.onCompleted();
    } finally {
        w.unsubscribe();
    }
}, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: Tx, using the worker here only to demo the slow response (so not production quality here). 
I will try your solution, but one thing i did not like is that onBackpressureBuffer() will lead to OOM, and onBackpressureDrop() seems to drop most recent items according to the spec, where I would be actually willing to drop only the old items with a  guarantee that the most recent item survives. (Should I use throttleLast instead?)

Comment: There is the `onBackpressureLatest` operator.

Comment: Heh, apparently we have been using too old of the version of rxjava, where it was not available. Will try with the newer rxjava and onBackpressureLatest then.

Comment: That worked as a charm, and this trick seems to be new (we had to upgrade to new rxjava version to access it). Now according to the spec flatMap(..., 1) seems to be doing exactly the same as concatMap(...). Is there any difference in behavior though?  I tried your code with concatMap instead and it actually produced undesired output:  source: 0, source: 0, target: 0, source: 1, ....

Comment: ConcatMap prefetches 1 source element while one is active whereas flatMap doesn't.